# Linux - Get environment variable name of a path

Tags: linux

I have a path like

```
/test/abc/efg/lmn/
```

I want to know if there is any environment variable set for this

like JAVA_TOP, XX_TOP etc.

is there any way to find that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

`printenv|grep /test/abc/efg/lmn/`

Comment: "NFS server not responding Still Trying"  i get this message

Comment: and with `set | grep /test/abc/efg/lmn/`?

Comment: printenv | grep /test/abc/efg/lmn/  - Worked. Please edit the answer

Comment: How have you fixed your error `NFS server not responding Still Trying`?

Comment: previously I just copied your command and pasted .. that gave the error.. but once i put space in between , as I mentioned earlier.. it worked

Comment: Please, can you try again without spaces because it should work?

Answer (score 1):

Within your shell (e.g. bash) you can show all environment variable and search for your string:

```
export | grep /test/abc/efg/lmn/
```

Within your application (e.g. Java) you can iterate over all environment variables set for the application.

1. Fetch all variables
2. Iterator over the result
3. Search in the string for the value

Example (missing the find):

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            String value = env.get(envName);
            // search within value here
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: export | grep /test/abc/efg/lmn/ also worked for me .. thanks for your help